# Joomla, Linking to other pages...?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm using Joomla on my site : [My Site](http://www.stuartblackett.com/solumac)

But I'm having a few issues, I've made each area a "Module" within Joomla and made them HTML Regions to edit the content etc.

But for the About Us / Our Work Pages' etc. I'd like to also link to another PHP Page, which has a different CSS / XHTML Layout, Rather than use the Joomla in built menu system and the one page template that i'm currently using.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create two templates and assign one template as default for whole site and the second one only for main page. Using this technique you can assign different teamplates for each page.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=303107

Answer (score 0):

In index.php, you can check the current article id or menu id

```
$ids = array(1,2,3)

if(in_array($article_id, $ids))
{

}else{

}
```

Now the articles with id 1,2 and 3 will have a slightly different layout.
If you want a total different layout, use ruslan's answer.